# Node-RED install script fails to install core

Tags: node.js, node-red

Node-RED install script when run on an Debian Server fails to install the `Node-RED core` and shows an error message

> Node-RED ERR! EAI_AGAIN

The Node-RED install script I am referring to can be found on [this site](https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/raspberrypi):

```
bash <(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/node-red/linux-installers/master/deb/update-nodejs-and-nodered)
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the DNS to Googles 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as briefly mentioned in this node-red unrelated forum post [here](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/downloading-node-issues/3789/2) solved the problem. The following [Article](https://www.ricmedia.com/set-permanent-dns-nameservers-ubuntu-debian-resolv-conf/) contains instructions on how to do so - and the [Wayback link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210622135614/https://www.ricmedia.com/set-permanent-dns-nameservers-ubuntu-debian-resolv-conf/) in case the first link breaks.